# Pushing files to avd using adb, changes are not saved

Tags: android, adb, genymotion, android-virtual-device

When I'm using Genymotion, whatever changes I do to the android vd  (eg change apps layout, push files, etc)- the android vd saves its state, so when I quit and start over again- it'll show the same app layout and the files I pushed will be there.

However, when using the android emulator, I've created an android x86 device, started it, changing the app layout and I'm using adb to push files to the avd. But when I quit the android emulator, I lose all the changes I made- any app layout cange or any file I pushed, will no longer be there when I re-open the same avd.
I made sure all of the avd files are chmodded to 777 (I'm on mac osx)

How do I keep all the changes to the avd persistent to the disk, in the same way it happens in genymotion?

Comment: Can you be more precise by providing a way to reproduce your problems?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to keep a snapshot of your emulator like this:
Go to your AVD manager, upon `Create...` make sure you tick `Snapshot` under Emulation Options (can be done as well on existing ones using edit).

Then when you click `Start..` you'll be given the following options:

- `Save to snapshot` - when you'll quit the vm a snapshot will be saved.
- `Launch from snapshot` - will load the latest saved snapshot.

Good luck, though I must say the whole snapshot thing did not go great for me, which made me switch to Genymotion.